# SSL Pinning in same request

Tags: ssl, okhttp

My question is that do i have to make a separate request to check `SSL Pinning` before every `Get/Post` Request

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().certificatePinner(
                new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                        .add(pinningUrl, "sha256/invalidPIN")
                        .build()).build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(pinningUrl)
                .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Or can i check it with every `Get/Post` like this

```
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                        .add(pinningUrl, "sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=")                    .build();
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().certificatePinner(certificatePinner).build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()         .url(getResources().getString(R.string.server_url_user_mgmt_services))
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application).post(body)
                        .build();

                client.newCall(request)
                        .enqueue(new Callback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Some error occured!\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                String str = response.body().toString();
                            }
                        });
```

If i check it on every request the request is executed but it does not check for `certificate` help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your first code example it looks like you are trying to pin with a URL instead of a hostname or wildcard.

You should configure it once on your OkHttpClient *per host* and then just make your normal requests.  The pins you define should have the host as the key, not the url.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html

```
 String hostname = "publicobject.com";
 CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
     .add(hostname, "sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=")
     .build();
 OkHttpClient client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
     .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
     .build();

 Request request = new Request.Builder()
     .url("https://" + hostname)
     .build();
 client.newCall(request).execute();
```